# Selenium + phpunit, Screenshots in Chrome and InternerExplorer Failure

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, selenium, phpunit

I have a test in phpunit that uses Selenium and take screenshots on failed tests and in key points.
It work on Firefox but not in Chrome and Internet explorer(remote win7 machine).

The code to take screenshots on failure and in key points are atandard:

```
protected $captureScreenshotOnFailure = TRUE;
protected $screenshotPath = 'results/';
protected $screenshotUrl = '__URL__';
```

And:

```
file_put_contents('MyScreenshot.png', base64_decode($this->captureEntirePageScreenshotToString()));
```

I tried to use chrome and InternetExplorer webdrivers but still nothing.

Selenium version: selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0
Command:

`../include/selenium-server-standalone.jar  -trustAllSSLCertificates -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=../include/chromedriver`
(On Ubuntu for chrome..)

What Am I missing?

Comment: How does it not work? Does it capture anything? Does it throw an error?

Comment: @Arran
Chrome/IE:
Issues while capturing the screenshot:
Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': ERROR: captureEntirePageScreenshot is only implemented for Firefox ("firefox" or "chrome", NOT "firefoxproxy") and IE non-HTA ("iexploreproxy", NOT "iexplore" or "iehta"). The current browser isn't one of them!
Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': ERROR: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...page-screenshot-880ca723ec0547699d717ae4f7a86606.png (No such file or directory)